# How to always have as many threads running simultaneously as the number of cores?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I have a vector of points. Each point is n-dimensional vector.
There are k=100 points for me.
I have to calculate for each point the values of the several functions of many variables.
After that I write the results to the txt file.

I have 4 cores. I use multithreading for this task. I want to have only
4 threads running simultaneously.
My threads are almost independent. They only share one resource. The txt file.
Each thread write the results at the end.
I use mutex to write to this file.

Now I have next solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; k+=number_of_threads){
// create 4 threads

// start function for each 4 threads

// join thread 1
// join thread 2
// join thread 3
// join thread 4
}
```

The problem is that new threads will not start until each thread ends.
This works. But there is a better solution, I think.

How can I start a new thread right after one of threads is finished?
And I want to have only 4 running threads running at the same time(4 is the number of cores)
I am using pthreads, by the way.

Comment: Is order important?  If not just split the data set into 4 equal pieces and let each thread work on one chunk.

Comment: The problem is the value k can change... Is there a way to add new thread after one of them is finished?

Comment: There are plenty of ways but they all cost time.  Can you just break the data set into `k` equal pieces?  Then you can have one thread per piece.

Comment: That's one hell of a calculation to justify multithreading on one txt file

Comment: If your really have to, how about [for each with parallel execution policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t)

Comment: There are *many* ways to handle this. One way would be to use a condition variable that would be signalled when a thread completed its work, the main thread would sleep on that condition variable and when woken, hand out more work to any idle threads. Or you can cut the cake in different ways. There are many options.

Comment: @nada

That's one hell of a calculation to justify multithreading on one txt file
Can you please explain what do you mean?
Is writing to one txt file is a bad idea?

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)

Comment: OpenMP is an easy way.

Comment: @Shawn I was told to use pthreads